# System of $4$ equations in three variables.

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

I'm preparing for my optimization exam and I'm having a really hard time solving the following system of equations. Can anyone suggest to me an approach to solving this, because I'm desperate right now:

$x_{2}x_{3}-k(x_{2}+x_{3})=0$

$x_{1}x_{3}-k(x_{1}+x_{3})=0$

$x_{1}x_{2}-k(x_{1}+x_{2})=0$

$x_{1}x_{2}+x_{1}x_{3}+x_{2}x_{3}=6$

Comment: Seriously? I thought it was because it has powers of 1.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks i fixed the title.

Comment: Is $k$ a supplied parameter or is it a variable as well?

Comment: Actually it's a parameter λ for optimization problems with one equality constraint. The general form is f'-λg'=0 and a system of 4 equations occurs from this.

Comment: You should remove "linear" from the first sentence.  This is not a linear system.

Comment: You have three variables, not four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: multiply the first equation by $x_1$, the second by $x_2$, the third by $x_3$ and sum them up. Use the fourth to get $4k=x_1x_2x_3$. Substitute this $k$, cancel and compare pairwise to get $xy=xz=yz=2$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: I've found the connection for 4k. After that, where do i have to substitute this?

Comment: @Georgio3 Substitute this $k=x_1x_2x_3/4$ into everywhere where $k$ appears and cancel $x_2x_3$ in the first equation etc. You can cancel since if one $x_k$ is zero then from the first three equations all are zeros, which contradicts the fourth.

Comment: What do you mean with the term 'cancel'? I'm Greek so I don't completely get the terminology

Comment: Ok, finally did it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$x_2=\frac {kx_3}{x_3-k}$$
 and similarly for $x_1$ from the second, which shows $x_1=x_2$.  Similarly you can show $x_2=x_3$  The last gives that each is $\sqrt 2$  Then the first gives $$2-2k\sqrt 2=0\\k=\frac {\sqrt 2}2\\x_1=x_2=x_3=\sqrt 2$$

Comment: That's a nice approach, too. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- Noting $(1),(2),(3)$ the three first equations you have 
$$(1)-(2) \iff (x_2-x_1)(x_3-k)=0\\(1)-(3)\iff(x_3-x_1)(x_2-k)=0\\(2)-(3)\iff(x_3-x_2)(x_1-k)=0$$ The result follows.